# не прорисовывается спрайт

Tags: python, pygame

Воспользовался туториалом для pygame на [сайте](https://pythonru.com/uroki/biblioteka-pygame-chast-2-rabota-so-sprajtami)

Основная проблема в том, что не прорисовывается спрайт, при этом ошибок не выдает. Код был переписан почти точь в точь.
Код:

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 650
FPS = 30

# Задаем цвета
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        
        
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += 5
        if self.rect.left > WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = 0


# Создаем игру и окно
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

# Цикл игры
running = True
while running:
    # Держим цикл на правильной скорости
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # Ввод процесса (события)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Обновление
    all_sprites.update()
    
    # Рендеринг
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    # После отрисовки всего, переворачиваем экран
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: вы его не переписовали а скопировали

Comment: @Danis , вопроса этот факт не отменяет. Почему не работает?

Comment: возможно у автора и у вас разные версии Python или Pygame

Comment: Это имеет место быть, спасибо, проверю